# Why header files in Xcode? Newbie wants to learn the ropes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header-files

I don't get why there is a separate header file .h for instance declarations and variable declarations, and then in the class file .m I write my classes.

Why not do it like interpreted languages? Just declare a function and reference it when needed. It seems like a lot of duplicate code writing to me and I wish it would make sense to me.

I found this post [Cost of Including Header Files in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777405/cost-of-including-header-files-in-objective-c?rq=1) and find it instructive.

Comment: I think you would understand it more if you had to learn C first. But yes, it is theoretically possible for the compiler to automatically generate the headers, but this is just not how Objective-C was implemented.

Comment: jeez, cant anyone ask a "dumb" question around here without getting a down vote? Sheesh...

Comment: I think you're right, this is not a bad question. I up-voted you because I think your question is good, but in the future, I would avoid starting a post with "I'm a noob", or ending it with "Thanks for anyone willing...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a good programming practice/standard than a hard rule. You can of course make declarations in the .m files (try it), just as you would in interpreted languages, but in general we don't do this because it's just not as organized.

The other reason is for modularity. But that's a big fish you need to catch by learning programming basics first ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is just the same as in C, where when you want to access something in one translation unit from another translation unit the thing has to be declared. Then at link time the linker will see that you're accessing a declaration of an object defined in the other translation unit and fix things up so you do actually use the thing across translation unit boundaries.

However this depends on the declarations being the same across translation units. Without header files you would have to write out the declarations identically in the two TUs, and every time you changed the declaration in one TU you'd have to change it in the others.

Headers exist so that declarations can be written once and then 'included' in any translation unit you want to use the item in, without having to carefully and manually synchronize the files.

Comment: I'm removing my comment because I found this post ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777405/cost-of-including-header-files-in-objective-c?rq=1) and its instructive.

Comment: @tim `@include` in php is mechanically similar to `#include` in C++ in that they both inject file contents into the current source. However the difference is in what the compiler needs to know for the code in one TU to make use of the code in another TU. In C++, the thing that needs to be known and identical between TUs is the declaration. The definition (e.g., a function's body) does not need to be known to other TUs. The definition can be hidden, and can be modified without re-compiling other TUs.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that the other answers don't mention is that methods defined in header files are public. The header file exposes the interface that other classes are allowed to use, while inside of the implementation file, you will often see things like:

```
@interface MyClass (PrivateAPI)

- (void)myPrivateMethod;

@end

@implementation MyClass

// All of the method implementations.

@end
```

This way only code within the scope of the implementation of MyClass can actually call myPrivateMethod. This is a very common and important technique in the practice of *encapsulation*.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a `.h` file in several other places without having to include the `.m`, which would result in duplicated code every time.

To sum up, by including the header (.h), you tell the compiler "the functions are here and here is their **signature** " (see the key word here?). By including the implementation (.m) you tell the compiler "here is the code for the functions defined earlier".